# Windows virtual printer that prints to TCP, HTTP or stream

Tags: windows, printing

Is there any virtual printer that can redirect print jobs to TCP or HTTP server, or just pass them to stream (for example `stdin` of some other process)?

Comment: I believe there is. Search "network printer windows"

Answer (score 1):

The architecture of a printer driver includes:

- A printer driver, which receives its input from GDI, and sends its output to ...
- A port monitor, which receives its input from the printer driver, and sends its output to wherever (e.g. to local hardware, or to remote/network printer).

So, you may be looking for a `port monitor` rather than a `printer driver`.

https://www.google.ca/search?q=printer+port+monitor finds various pages which might interest you.